# FFMpeg : Add audio stream via -filter_complex

Tags: ffmpeg

In Reference to https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg
I have a bunch of images. and I want to make a video using these images.
Below is my code for `FFMpeg`. But the problem is how can I append an audio file to `-filter_complex` (with bitrate)

```
ffmpeg \
-loop 1 -i input0.png \
-loop 1 -i input1.png \
-loop 1 -i input2.png \
-loop 1 -i input3.png \
-loop 1 -i input4.png \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v0]; \
 [1:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v1]; \
 [2:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v2]; \
 [3:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v3]; \
 [4:v]trim=duration=15,fade=t=in:st=0:d=0.5,fade=t=out:st=14.5:d=0.5[v4]; \
 [v0][v1][v2][v3][v4]concat=n=5:v=1:a=0,format=yuv420p[v]" -map "[v]" out.mp4
```

Comment: You need to show the complete console output from your command.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard this is the exact command from https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg you answer and the OP was not able to add the audio input map to the output. Please help him and others including me.

Comment: @bahadorkhanalizadeh You can do it in two passes if you want. -i audio.mp3 -codec copy

Comment: Answered in linked question with updated example.

Comment: you "should" be able to just add it as an input, does it not work?